# Linq query comparison

Tags: wpf, linq, datagrid

When running a Linq on two datagrids in wpf can you have the query look for different formats to matches.

for example phones numbers. In my first table my phone number format is 
123-456-7890 and the other table the format is 1234567890

is there a way to have this still recognize this as a matching value using a linq query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select your data from the database, why not to use replace there

```
REPLACE ( yourColumnName , '-', '' )
```

this will remove all the '-' characters you data from both tables will have same format.

Answer (score 1):

Yours worked correctly but I decide to go with this in my linq query

```
 .Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray())
```